# PHP code won't update Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working my assignment and i can't get my update to work with my database.
Here is my form that holds the data.

```
<form name="edit" method="post" action="process/editRecord.php">

    <p class="indent">
      <label for="projectName">Edit Project Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="projectName" id="projectName" value="<?php echo $projectName; ?>">
    </p>

    <p class="indent">
      <label for="projectSoftware">Edit Project Software</label>
      <input type="text" name="projectSoftware" id="projectSoftware" value="<?php echo $projectSoftware; ?>" >
    </p>


    <p class="indent">
      <label for="projectDescription">Edit Project Description</label>
      <textarea name="projectDescription" id="projectDescription" cols="150" rows="10" ><?php echo $projectDescription; ?></textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="indent">
      <label for="projectImage">Edit Project Image</label>
      <input type="text" name="projectImage" id="projectImage" value="<?php echo $projectImage; ?>" >
    </p>

    <p class="indent">
      <label for="projectInformation">Edit Project Information</label>
      <textarea name="projectInformation" id="projectInformation" cols="400" rows="10" ><?php echo $projectInformation; ?></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update">
    </p>

</form>
```

And then is the process.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require('../../includes/conn.inc.php');
require('../../includes/functions.inc.php');
// sanitize user variables
$sprojectName = safeString($_POST['projectName']);
$sprojectSoftware = safeString($_POST['projectSoftware']);
$sprojectDescription = safeString($_POST['projectDescription']);
$sprojectImage = safeString($_POST['projectImage']);
$sprojectInformation = safeString($_POST['projectInformation']);
$sprojectID = safeInt($_POST['projectID']);
// prepare SQL
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE projects SET projectName =?, projectSoftware =?, projectDescription=?, projectImage =?, projectInformation =? WHERE projectID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssi', $sprojectName, $sprojectSoftware, $sprojectDescription, $sprojectImage, $sprojectInformation, $sprojectID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

header("Location: ../../php/projects.php");
// redirect browser
exit; // make sure no other code executed
?>
```

I get no errors when using this and it doesn't update my database but goes back to relevant projects page.

Comment: what the heck is that `safeString()` function? just use prepared statements alone. you can't see any error message because most likely you haven't turned it on with the fact that you're not checking whether the statement actually executed

Comment: the safeString is sanataizing it so you can't sql inject it, and what prepared statemants

Comment: This prepared statement: `$mysqli->prepare(...`, see [PHP: MySQLi > Quick start guide > Prepared Statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: '$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE projects SET projectName =?, projectSoftware =?, projectDescription=?, projectImage =?, projectInformation =? WHERE projectID = ?");' so whats this line doing then if not preparing it

Comment: Ok, let's try it the other way round: is `safeString`removing characters?  Or is it simply calling some encoding function like e.g. mysqli::real_escape_string? Or ...?

Comment: This is what it is doing 
`function safeString($str)
 {
  return filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
 }`

Comment: You're using a prepared statement + parameters anyway, _this_ is what actually prevents this kind of sql injections in your case. The `safeString` function is superfluous (for preventing sql inections) at best.

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedback, but _still_ no idea why it doesn't upadate the database ?!?

Comment: `$_POST['projectID']` its not in the form

Comment: @Dagon *Thats it* thank god i would have never though of that beacus ei amd working with a fellow student and his doesn't use and id so we never saw the problem

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue

> $_POST['projectID'] its not in the form – Dagon

Comment: In that case you should probably not only set display_error=On but also raise the [error_reporting](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) level (both preferably not within the script but e.g. in the php.ini, since in a production environemt sending the complete error message to the client [should be avoided](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_Leakage)); `safeInt($_POST['projectID'])` should have resulted in an "undefined index" message.